# Verify my account

Tags: facebook-messenger

My device has been reset before I got it.  I'm being asked to sign in with the Google Account that was previously synced on the device. I don't know the previous email. How do I change the email?

Answer (score 0):

It's locked by FRP.
Do a simple thing.
Try the following methods on your phone.
[Unlock FRP](https://www.unlockunit.com/blog/bypass-google-account-verification-factory-reset-protection/)

If they don't work, check your phone manufacturer's website or contact their customer help centre.